# Image Processing: Removing noise of processed image OPENCV - JAVA

Tags: android, opencv

I have process an image for OCR, I encountered a problem where the processed image has too much noise. I am a beginner in this type of programming and Im just wondering if you guys can help me denoise it?

Here's the code I have so far

```
File newFile = new File(mFile);

        orig = Imgcodecs.imread(newFile.getAbsolutePath(),Imgcodecs.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
        Mat small = new Mat();
        Imgproc.pyrDown(orig,small);
        final Size kernelSize = new Size(3, 3);
        final Point anchor = new Point(-1, -1);
        final int iterations = 3;

        Mat kernel = Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_ELLIPSE, kernelSize);

        Imgproc.GaussianBlur(small,small, new Size(3,3),0);
        Imgproc.erode(small, small,kernel,anchor,iterations);
        Imgproc.dilate(small,small,kernel);

        Imgproc.adaptiveThreshold(small,small,255,Imgproc.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY,45,2);

        Mat kernel2 = Imgproc.getGaussianKernel(6,2);

        Imgproc.dilate(small,small,kernel2);
        Imgproc.erode(small,small,kernel);

        Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(small.cols(), small.rows(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Utils.matToBitmap(small, bm);
```

And here are the outputs

**Sample 1**

[image]

**Sample 2**

[image]

Comment: have you found any solution

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try [fastNlMeansDenoising](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/photo/doc/denoising.html#fastnlmeansdenoising) method?

And I think GaussianBlur is also good method for denoising.(after your code)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Im already using GaussianBlur as you can see `Imgproc.GaussianBlur(small,small, new Size(3,3),0);`